# Controlling the layout of sprites

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm creating a Cocos2d game which will have between 4 to 12 moveable rectangle sprites that should start off in the bottom 1/3 of the screen.  The user will be able to drag those moveable sprites (one at at time) to the top of screen and let them go on top of other non-moveable sprites.  I'm trying to determine the best/easiest way to layout the moveable sprites and be able to keep track of their originating location.

The reason I'd like to keep track of the moveable sprites orginal location is that I'd like to give the users the ability to tap on them and have them go back to their original spot (if they're not happy with where they've placed them).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new class with the Sprite object and with the original x, y locations and with the desired behaviors that respond to moving, click, etc.

This way, if you want to add other attributes to the Sprites, you can easily do so by adding them to your new class.

Comment: Do you mean I should create a sub class of a Sprite or should I create a class that has a Sprite attribute which would point to the Sprite I'm trying to keep track of?

Comment: Then just create a class with a CSSprite attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand, did you mean a CCSprite?  I don't know what a CSSprite is.

Comment: yeah, sorry! `CCSprite` is correct. I mixed up the extra C with S.